# Cannot Deserialize LifeRay Service Model Object from JSON that came from ElasticSearch, Default Constructor not Found

Tags: json, elasticsearch, serialization, deserialization, liferay

Using LifeRay portal and ElasticSearch, Serializing custom object composed from ServiceModel Objects, Serialisation goes fine:

```
public String toJSON(){
    return JSONFactoryUtil.looseSerializeDeep(this);
}
```

I index this into ES which is also fine, it contains list of those objects as well as single object, no problem.

When I Deserialize this I get this Error:

```
10:10:53,972 ERROR [ExceptionHandlerBridgeImpl:78] jodd.json.JsonException: Default ctor not found for: eu.project.drives.platform.model.model.TainingProvider
```

For each parameter which is Object from Service Model.

Code (should be ok as well, example for one field):

```
JSONObject obj = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(h.getSourceAsString());
                
                TainingProvider t = JSONFactoryUtil.looseDeserialize(obj.getString("provider"), TainingProvider.class);
```

I cannot simply induce the Default constructor since it is generated by service builder nor I can do the "TainingProviderImpl.class" since it is different project but the Impl class should be what is called through the "TainingProvider.class" and it includes the default constructor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The provided type when doing a deserialize is an interface in your example, so the internal Parser (here Jodd) might not find an implementation class to use as a bean class.

I did not find a nice solution, but used the internal Jodd parser directly.
When you subclass `jodd.json.JsonParser` you can overwrite the protected method for instantiation.

```
@Override
protected Object newObjectInstance(Class targetType) {
    if (targetType.isAssignableFrom(TainingProvider.class)) {
        return TainingProviderLocalServiceUtil.createTainingProvider(0L);
    }
    return super.newObjectInstance(targetType);
}
```

Now you can use the parser directly via `parser.parse(obj.getString("provider"), TainingProvider.class)`

I am not sure if it possible to hook in this instantiation hints to Liferays JSONFactoryUtil, which would be nicer instead of having a direct dependency to the jodd Parser in your module.